# Проблема с FlexBox в Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

Как блоки выглядят в `IE 11`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как они должны выглядеть и выглядят в `Firefox, Chrome, Opera`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данные блоки сделаны с помощью `FlexBox`. Самое интересное то, что не работает только в некоторых местах, например в других частях верстки, `FlexBox` работает. Я не могу уже долгое время понять с чем это связано и как это решить. Мне давали скриншоты на которых видно, что даже в IE 10 все корректно отображается. Прилагаю ссылку на саму верстку: https://uzinouzi.github.io/testtemplate/ так как воспроизводимый пример создать невозможно, ибо проблема может быть вовсе не во `FlexBox`.

Comment: Не знаю, что вы на страницу такого разместили там, но я ее закрыл после того, как счетчик пошел на второй десяток мегабайт, а она все еще была пустой :Р

Comment: недавно тоже страдал от похожей фигни, выяснилось, что IE не понимает автоматических ширины и высоты, и если заранее прописать ее везде, то проблема не повторяется там

Comment: @Visman, на сайте нет ничего такого, там подключен только slick, минибиблиотека для svg и все. Вес большой, потому что не применялись никакие приемы оптимизации пока что, ибо это тестовый шаблон, как доделаю его я в любом случаи оптимизирую верстку. Вес большой из-за фона на первом экране.

Comment: @PaulWall, например у первого экрана стоит min-height 900px, но слайдер все равно съехал

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi ну мин height надо с max-height использовать обязательно. Если есть к примеру 3 блока div>div>div, то для больного IE у каждого должна быть ширина и высота, иначе если влепить только последнему, эксплорер сам ее дорисует своим воображением

Comment: @PaulWall, добавил max-height, не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Я же ответил уже на вопрос - везде ширину пишите, эксплорер не понимает. Вот два скриншота блоков, вбил туда ширину и все встало http://joxi.ru/ZrJqx8Et1VOplA
http://joxi.ru/YmEklRquZ4kElA

Comment: Попробуйте сделать это на первом экране, там не работает, я пробовал.

Comment: на каком первом экране))

Comment: Там где слайдер,  он с помощью флексов должен выровняться по центру по вертикали, но он съехал вверх

Comment: height 1200 если поставить без Min-height?

Comment: Тогда с адаптивом проблемы будут. Но я не пробовал пока что